# plotting a quadratic function in R

Tags: r, plot, quadratic

Here's how I plotted a quadratic curve:

```
factor <- 1:7

data <- c(0.1375000,0.2500000,0.3416667,0.4583333,0.7250000,0.9166667,1.0000000)

plot(factor, fitted(lm(data~factor+I(factor^2))), type="l")
```

[image]

I try to do the same with my another data.

```
factor1<-c(2833,2500,2437,2124,1382,3736,2100,1844,2740,957,1614,1100,1550,3858,2430,2139,1812,1757,1847,945)

data1<-c(0.95,0.88,0.88,0.93,0.81,0.67,0.55,0.53,0.52,0.90,0.87,0.20,0.28,-0.16,0.23,0.11,0.26,0.08,0.73,0.76)

plot(factor1,fitted(lm(data1~factor1+I(factor1^2))), type="l")
```

[image]

I think this is because the second dataset is not sorted but I thought R automatically sorts them before plotting them.

Could anyone tell me how to plot a quadratic line in the second plot.

Comment: Nope. R doesn't automatically sort points. Not sure where you got that idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can order it first

```
i<-order(factor1)
plot(factor1[i],fitted(lm(data1[i]~factor1[i]+I(factor1[i]^2))), type="l")
```